# Is e4defrag ready for use?

Tags: 10.10, ext4, defrag

I want defragment my root ext4 partition after upgrade to 10.10. But I can't find **e4defrag** in standart repos. May I build it from source? And is it safe for use?

UPD: Now in 12.04, we have e4defrag in repos. Just tried it, and it works well! I see some speed improvement. Simply run e4defrag /dev/sda1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to one of its developers, Akira Fujita, e4defrag needs more feedback - which IMO translates to "not ready for prime time". I wouldn't use any defragmentation tool that's not thoroughly tested.

Here are some interesting slides from his recent [talk at the LinuxCon 2010](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/slides/2010/linuxcon_japan/linuxcon_jp2010_fujita.pdf).

---

`e4defrag` is now in the development version of Ubuntu 12.04, see its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/e4defrag.8.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any up-to-date information? Is there any source, where I can check on my own? Surprisingly Google coudln't answere this for me.

Comment: Good link - but this answer should be updated, it's been in official repo for some time.