# Is it safe to defrag ext4 file system using e4defrag?

Tags: ext4, defrag

My file system partition is 90GB, and now 75% of the space is free after removing 53GB of recovered files using `photorec` from my home directory. I just want to know, is it safe to defrag the whole file system using `e4defrag`, or are there any extra precautions that I should be aware of?

Comment: Close-voters: Why would this be off-topic? This is a question about using Ubuntu software. Please see the FAQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is e4defrag ready for use?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11384/is-e4defrag-ready-for-use)

Answer (score 24):

- It is safe to use, otherwise it would not be available or have a big red warning when trying to use it.
- [Here is a good document on ext4 and defragging](https://web.archive.org/web/20130308164254/http://events.linuxfoundation.org/slides/2010/linuxcon_japan/linuxcon_jp2010_fujita.pdf).
- Do not expect to see dramatic benefits since ext4 is made to work without the need for defragmentation.

Comment: I've just extended my raid, and used e2resize to extend the file system too. In such cases it could be useful to run a defrag.